# How to use ObjectPool in detached thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

The principal of object polling is very interesting

To me it can't be strong without the multi-threading execution.

For exemple i try this library [furious-objectpool](https://code.google.com/p/furious-objectpool/)

The debugging show that the create/passivate methods are executed in the same request thread, how could i take advantage of this principal using it in another thread?

Answer (score 1):

Object Pools are rather discouraged in Java. They are quite an expensive concept, usually way more expensive than just creating an object (new operator requires ~10 instructions, acquire/release in pools typically need MUCH more).

Also such long lived objects in Java tend to mess with GC not being able to clean up resources.

I would really encourage you to use some DI container with some nice stateless beans. It is both super fast (usually only 1 object per type) and nicely managable.

However, if you really need to use a pool, make sure that you use it for an object that has a very expensive construction process - typically some sort of network connections (database connections are the most common example).

As for another thread stuff: such pools are (or what is the point anyways?) always thread safe. Typical usage scenario would involve some sort of a server (like REST service) that accepts and executes plenty of user requests per minute.

Edit:
And please - don't use a technology/library just because it looks cool. It more often than not will bring you trouble in the long run.